# Hot reload stuck after first try

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, hot-reload

I am using vscode to developing flutter application , I don't know what is going on ! When I save project and try to hot reload just one time it's work and notification of hot reloading(`Performing hot reload`) remain at bottom of vscode and next hot reloading not works.

[image]

Vscode not throw any error or something to catch a problem so I run application with `run` command and after hot reload, this is it's result :

```
Flutter run key commands.
r Hot reload. 
R Hot restart.
h Repeat this help message.
d Detach (terminate "flutter run" but leave application running).
c Clear the screen
q Quit (terminate the application on the device).
An Observatory debugger and profiler on sdk gphone x86 arm is available at: http://127.0.0.1:40989/zVisdoiRRE8=/

Flutter DevTools, a Flutter debugger and profiler, on sdk gphone x86 arm is available at: http://127.0.0.1:9101?uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A40989%2FzVisdoiRRE8%3D%2F

Running with unsound null safety
For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety

Performing hot reload...
```

Now when I press r , hot reload not working .

I am using fvm and This is my sdk version :

```
$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel unknown, 2.0.6, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 2.0.6 at /home/alt/fvm/versions/2.0.6
    • Framework revision 1d9032c7e1 (5 weeks ago), 2021-04-29 17:37:58 -0700
    • Engine revision 05e680e202
    • Dart version 2.12.3

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /mnt/SSDP/Sdk/android/
    • Platform android-S, build-tools 30.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /mnt/SSDP/Sdk/android
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = /mnt/SSDP/Sdk/android/
    • Java binary at: /mnt/SSDP/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at google-chrome

[✓] Android Studio
    • Android Studio at /mnt/SSDP/android-studio/
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • android-studio-dir = /mnt/SSDP/android-studio/
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.56.2)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension version 3.23.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 10 (API 29)
      (emulator)
    • Chrome (web)                       • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome
      91.0.4472.77

• No issues found!
```

- I faced this problem with Android studio too.

Comment: did you get this working ?

Comment: I have this problem still.

Comment: so what do  you any alternatives ?

Answer (score 0):

I switched back to Android Studio and after a fresh install (also deleting all contents and settings of existing installation) this error disappeared.

Since I have not found "the" solution to this problem, here are some hints on how you might solve it:

**Android Studio**

You can try to toggle the "Scope analysis to current package" flag. That solved a similar issue for a colleague.

If this doesn't work, you can click on "View analyzer options" to open some analysis insights in your browser. Maybe you find some hint there.

[image: Screenshot from Android Studio]

**Visual Studio Code**

Go to settings (<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>) and filter by `@ext:dart-code.dart-code` to get many dart analyzer specific settings. You can try to access the analyzer log files to find information why it is stuck or change the "Debug Extension Backend Protocol" setting.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I face it I will terminate every instance of gradle and it works well. Hot reload works again. On the linux in the command line:

```
ps aux | grep gradle | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
```